# How to implements Facebook's Comments Plugin in React Native app?

Tags: facebook, react-native, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I'm trying to load the facebook's comments plugin in React Native app, like an image below :

[image]

Is it possible ? 
How to implements Facebook's Comments Plugin in React Native app ?

Comment: I also wonder this. If use Webview is optimized?

Comment: Did you guys manage to implement this via "WebView"? There seems to be an issue: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/1448

Comment: Have you try this one? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible ?

Currently, it is impossible. Facebook currently only supports this plugin for web.

> How to implements Facebook's Comments Plugin in React Native app ?

You may need a `Webview`/`Webkit` component to create an embedded browser, then the job is as for a web (of course only inside that `webview`/`webkit`)