# How to add Facebook Comments Plugin in React Native using Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, facebook-comments

I am developing a news app using React Native and Expo. At the end of each of the news page, I need a Facebook comments section, like the following:[image]

I have only found answers for adding comments in web page but not in mobile apps. The closest thing I've found is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145552/how-to-implements-facebooks-comments-plugin-in-react-native-app) which recommends using a Web View. Do we have to use Web View or is there any other alternative way? And if we use a web view, how do I know what url to provide in the source uri field?